# Similar words/phrases random generator

Tags: word-choice, software, tools

I recall using a website where a user could input a set of words or phrases and the website would generate similar words or phrases, which "felt like" (but didn't repeat) the original words/phrases. I have not been able to find such a resource online since. Is anyone familiar with a website like this?

Comment: When you say 'felt like', do you mean synonyms or just the general style? And what search terms have you tried?

Comment: General style, believe it or not.  It worked with proper nouns--not just various words.  I have tried various "random word generators".

Comment: It wasn't this, was it? https://github.com/williamgilpin/cfgen Less of a website, more of a project...

Comment: @286642 Perhaps you could provide an example?

Comment: on a band's subreddit, somebody guessed what the band's upcoming album could be called based on the previous album titles.  It obviously wasn't correct, but all of the options were super cool regardless. @rolfedh

Comment: @DM_with_secrets i've never seen a github page before . . . how do I use it?

Comment: Ah - I think you have to do what it says under Requirements and Installation, but it looks  a bit technical for me... And in that case it clearly wasn't the one you'd seen before!

Comment: For synonyms I use https://www.thesaurus.com

Answer (score 1):

[Related Words](https://relatedwords.org/) lets you type a word or phrase and spits out related words and phrases that have a similar feel. Perhaps this is what you're thinking of?

Alternatively, [Visuwords](https://visuwords.com/) lets you type a word or phrase, then visualizes related words, concepts and ideas.

Comment: related words is definitely close.  thanks for sharing!